# How can I get the total number of installed importers?

Tags: php, import

WordPress lists available importers at Tools > Import. As an administrator I can install importers from this list.

How can I get a count of the installed importers?

`get_importers()` seems useful but when I call that function in either a parent or child theme I get a fatal error.

Comment: It looks like [`get_importers()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_importers/) is only available in the admin section of WordPress. You could try including [the necessary file](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-admin/includes/import.php).

Comment: Thanks @Howdy_McGee